# Adding libraries to NetBeans project without Maven

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a project in NetBeans and a jar library that I want to add to it. But I don't know exactly how. I know that in Eclipse this can be done by creating a lib folder in the project and putting the jars into it, but is this gonna work in NetBeans?

I tried to do it this way and run the project, but the exception it throws makes me think that the library isn't found by the program. I haven't found the library in the Maven repository, so I want to add it directly. I'm using NetBeans 12.0.

Comment: How was the project initially created in NetBeans? For example, was it: File > New Project > Java with Maven? Probably not, given your question. But if it was created with Maven there should be a `pom.xml` file, for adding new JAR dependencies. Was it created with File > New Project > Java with Ant? If so, then you can use File > Project Properties > Libraries to add a new Jar file to the classpath (or modulepath for modules). Or was the project created some other way?

Comment: It was created as Java with Maven. But as I said in the comment below, I don't want to deal with Maven stuff, I just want to plug this bunch of jars that I have into the project all at once and go on with programming as it is done in Eclipse. How do I do that?

Comment: If you have a Maven-based project and you don't want to use Maven, then why not create an Ant-based project instead: No Maven required. Now you can add all those JARs at once. But you may run afoul of transitive dependencies (libraries which rely on other _missing_ libraries) - and find yourself wishing for a tool which manages those dependencies automatically - like Maven (or Gradle or Ivy).

Comment: You can [edit] your question to (a) describe the steps you took to set up your project and (b) show us the error you are getting.

Comment: Already created it (Ant project) and it's working properly. But what I wanted is the possibility to manage dependencies of the build system combined with the option of adding them directly of the IDE. Is it possible with NetBeans or is it just a wrapper around the build system that doesn't have its own functionality of this type?

Answer (score 0):

You may add you local library to your netbeans project, but this would be overwritten as this project is managed by maven. The better choice is to add your jar file to your local .m2 storage. You may your library by the command:

```
mvn install:install-file \
-Dfile=<path-to-file> \
-DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
-Dversion=<version> \
-Dpackaging=<packaging> \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

path-to-file: the path to the file to load e.g → c:\kaptcha-2.3.jar

group-id: the group that the file should be registered under e.g → com.google.code

artifact-id: the artifact name for the file e.g → kaptcha

version: the version of the file e.g → 2.3

packaging: the packaging of the file e.g. → jar

As alternative you can directly add your jar as dependency too your maven project. You should use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Name_Your_JAR.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But I don't want any Maven stuff. I just want to drag a jar (actually a bunch of jars) into the project somewhere and be happy. And I don't want to write these dependency tags for each jar when there are bunch of them. Isn't it possible with NetBeans?

Comment: This is a maven managed project. From my pov not as persistent solution if you change your maven project you will lose your jar classpath dependency